# How to make a jquery countdown timer connected to ajax action?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, pdo

What im looking to accomplish is on my system when you click an action, the menu is hidden (disabled) and replaced with a count down timer. After the count down timer is up I'd like the menu to be unhidden and slide back down.

When I perform the action I hide the menu you thats running fine. But when it comes to counting down when its available I googled some and found this and changed it to try it out. But this doesnt seem to do anything.

Here is the timer code:

```
 var coolDownTime = 10;

    function coolDownTimer() {
        setTimeOut (function() {
            if(coolDownTime != 0) {
                coolDownTime--;

                coolDownTimer();
            } else {
                $("#target_area").slideDown('medium');
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Here is how I hide the menu:

```
 $('[name=action]').click(function () { 
   $("#target_area").slideUp('medium');

   return false;
 });
```

I do some other ajax in here to perform some actions and then I slide the menu up.

At this point I'd like the countdown to begin and when the countdown is up, I want the
actions to come back so they can have the option to continue once more.

The problem with the current method I believe is if I put that timer code in the same click statement I hide the menu in it just stops working completely. I'm very lost. Has anyone done something similar and know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WIth a lil bit of digging and logic I came up with this . .

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).html('show')
    $('.show').slideUp('medium');
    var count = 10,
        counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

    function timer() {
        count--;
        if (count <= 0) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            $('.trigger').html('hide');
            $('.show').slideDown('medium');
            return;
        }
        console.log(count);
        $('.timer').html(count);
    }

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/VDPEw/)

Comment: This actually works perfectly but how would I make the countdown appear when its hidden so you can actually see it? And also do you know how to go about making sure they can't just refresh the page and reset it?